# string_replace replacing very first segment in loop

Tags: php, iteration, str-replace

This question is based on my previous question. This is my code.

```
$this->logger->debug($datauser);   // [ZN1961] => Array([#A] => 12 >  4 [#B] => 12 >  2 ), [ZN1962] => Array ([#A] => 20 >  4 [#B] => 20  >  2 )
logicexpression = ((#A) OR (#B) );

$newArr = array();
foreach ($datauser as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $logname => $cond) {
        $this->logger->debug($cond);     /// WHEN DEBEG HERE it gives correctly the $cond in each iteration          
        $logicexpression =str_replace($logname, $cond, $logicexpression);
    }
$this->logger->debug($logicexpression ); // here I am always getting (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2)
    }
`
```

So my problem  is as I mentioned in the code I am always getting (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2).
So the output is,

```
@547,12 >  4
@547, 12 >  2
@557, (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2)
@547, 20 >  4
@547, 20 >  2
@557, (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2) // here it should has to come as (20 >  4) OR (20 >  2)`
```

Even I am getting `$cond` correctly while debugging couldn't replace the relevant `$cond` in iteration. I couldn't understand why ? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a new variable `$newlogicexpression` inside the iteration, otherwise after the first iteration you don't have `(#A) OR (#B)` in `$logicexpression` anymore and the replace won't work...

```
$logicexpression = ((#A) OR (#B) );
foreach ($datauser as $key => $value) {
    $newlogicexpression = $logicexpression;
    foreach ($value as $logname => $cond) {
        $newlogicexpression = str_replace($logname, $cond, $newlogicexpression);
    }
    $this->logger->debug($newlogicexpression);
}
```

Comment: I have slightly change the codes. since if I add an array couldn't get the correct replacement at once. Could you please help me with that

Comment: guess i didn't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to replace (#A) OR (#B) this with relavant $cond. like first iteration (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2) second iteration (20 >  4) OR (20 >  2). Here my problem is in every iteration I am getting the result as (12 >  4) OR (12 >  2)

Comment: It helped . Thanks